# Octave replacement of listdlg, msgbox, etc

Tags: user-interface, matlab, octave

Matlab has msgbox, listdlg, textscan, and many [other functions](http://wiki.octave.org/wiki.pl?MissingMatlabFunctions) that Octave apparently doesn't have. Is there any extra library with functions like this? Or perhaps different-named functions that will show a message dialog, let user select a data file to process, and read in formatted file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [octave forge](http://octave.sourceforge.net).  It has [msgbox](http://octave.sourceforge.net/java/function/msgbox.m.html), [listdlg](http://octave.sourceforge.net/java/function/listdlg.m.html) and other related methods.  There are installation instructions on the home page.

Comment: How do I install them? I installed missing-functions package but apparently that's not the right one.

Comment: I think thats the `java` package: http://octave.sourceforge.net/java/overview.html

Comment: also make sure you are using the 3.4.x version of Octave not the 3.2.x

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a Debian-based distribution like Ubuntu or Linux Mint, then you can use the functions mentioned (msgbox, listdlg etc.) by installing the precompiled package [octave-java](http://packages.debian.org/sid/octave-java).

In general, the Debian project (and, by side-effect, derived distributions) tries to package as many packages as reasonable from [Octave-Forge](http://octave.sourceforge.net/packages.php) to provide a Free alternative to proprietary packages like Matlab (sometimes, these packages can provide also implementation of functions of some of the parts of extra/paid Matlab toolboxes).

I am sure that other fine, reputable, high profile Linux distributions (like Fedora) also provide many packages from Octave-Forge, as [they also have a policy](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Octave) for such packages.